# Updating interface handler issue

Tags: android, android-handler

So I have these lines of codes in my android app, `wifiScrollViewText` is of type String, I set to whatever message I want to append to the ViewText: `wifiScrollViewText` through the handler ... The `readableNetmask` in my case is 255.255.255.0 , and the `readableIPAddress` is 10.0.0.11 ... If I deletes Update 2 the Netmask will appear on the textview ... but if I add Update 2 line of codes, the textview will show the IP twice instead of Netmask then IPAddress. I think the solution is to wait for the first update to finish before starting the second handler Object!

```
// Update 1 
wifiScrollViewText = readableNetmask + "\n";
handler.post(new UpdateWiFiInfoTextViewRunnable());

// Update 2     
wifiScrollViewText = readableIPAddress + "\n";
handler.post(new UpdateWiFiInfoTextViewRunnable());
```

Runnable:

```
static public class UpdateWiFiInfoTextViewRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        wifi_info_textView.append(wifiScrollViewText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The two `Runnables` will not be run until the current message/code on the main thread is done executing, so by the time the two `Runnables` are run the `wifiScrollViewText` variable points to the same text. You'll need to hold the two pieces of text in either two separate variables or in a list(if you plan doing multiple appends) and pop them in a single run of the `Runnable`:

```
List<String> mUpdates = new ArrayList<String>();
// Update 1 
mUpdates.add(readableNetmask + "\n");
// Update 2     
mUpdates.add(readableIPAddress + "\n");
handler.post(new UpdateWiFiInfoTextViewRunnable());
```

where:

```
static public class UpdateWiFiInfoTextViewRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < mUpdates.size(); i++) {
            wifi_info_textView.append(mUpdates.get(i));
        }
        mUpdates.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: there is another thing i would like you to help me with: I will post another question .... Thank you